# How to post data to Firebase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need C# Firebase CRUD sample without thirdy party DLL, because all of them give version error in .NET Framework 4.0 with Visual Studio.

This is how I get the data:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var response = wb.DownloadString("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/.json");
}
```

But how can I post data? I have used this, but it gives error response 405.

```
var response=wb.UploadValues("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com","POST", data);
```

Comment: Have you tried FireSharp?